# In Star Trek, are there any (named) low-ranking older officers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, starfleet-rank, age

Of course, I mean besides Lt. JG Picard in "[Tapestry](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tapestry_(episode))":

[image]

Is it just Hollywood bias or are we to believe that officers either get promoted, get killed, or retire if their career is not advancing?

Comment: What do you consider old? What do you consider the highest "low" rank?

Comment: Once consideration; if you are looking at TNG, the Enterprise was pretty much a prime posting, as is mentioned by a few who join the crew at various points.  So, there's a pretty good chance that competition to be a crew member helps weed out some older, lower-rank people.

Comment: Damn.  I read the headline, and came here planning to mention Lt. JG Picard.  You beat me to it!

Comment: I believe the US military has a rule that if you are passed over for promotion twice in succession, you must leave the service - you can't serve indefinitely without advancing. It's not unreasonable to guess that Starfleet might have something similar.

Comment: I felt my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything you'd want adding before considering an acceptance?

Comment: In the movie Fort Apache (1948) all the officers are company grade officers up to Captain rank, except for Lieutenant Colonel Owen Thursday (who also seems to be a brevet or honorary major general) and Captain York who is a colonel in the epilogue.  And many of those junior officers seem to be middle aged or elderly. Very different from the modern US military or ThePopMachine's impression of Starfleet.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Lt Jg [Reg Barclay](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Reginald_Barclay) was (approx) 42 years of age when we meet him in TNG: Hollow Pursuits. That seems rather old for such a low rank.

[image]

Lt Jg [Janice Rand](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Janice_Rand) was (approx) 51 years of age when she was promoted to her rank.

[image]

---

Ensign [Alans](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alans) was a technical specialist (a volcanologist).
When we meet him, he's (approx) 45 years of age.

[image]

Ensign [Cheney](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cheney)'s age isn't described in canon, but she doesn't look that young (mid-50's?)

[image]

---

Obviously it's a bit different for longer-lived species, but Ensign [Chu'Lak](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chu%27lak) was aged 77 when he was commissioned an Ensign.

[image]

And Ensign Tuvok was approx 85 years old when he rejoined Starfleet as an Ensign.

[image]

Comment: The apocrypha puts Barclay closer to 36 at his first appearance, though that is still old for a JG.

Comment: @Richard : Nice list!  You might want to add transporter chief Kyle from the original Enterprise, who was later serving on the Reliant (you can see him on the bridge in *The Wrath of Khan*).  I doubt his rank was that high, even at that point.

Comment: @Praxis - In the absence of a canon confirmation of his rank, I'm hesitant to add him.

Comment: @Richard : That's fair.

Comment: @Richard:  The Vulcans, although technically true, don't really fit the gist of the question.   For one thing, they don't LOOK old (speaks to the Hollywood bias point).   For another, I believe in most cases, the Vulcan have had multiple careers before joining Starfleet.   I would accept the example if we knew a Vulcan who was a Lieutenant/Ensign who had served for many decades.  (?)

Comment: @Richard:   Additional possible answer [Lt.Cmdr Albert](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Albert).   He seems to be around 45-50, had a son presumably at least around 20.  Now, Lt. Cmdr is not exactly a low rank, but usually everyone we meet makes Commander before they turn 50.

Comment: If Star Trek gave more than lip service to real-world military protocol, I suspect some of these people might be [mustangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustang_(military_officer)) or [direct commission officers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_commission_officer).

Comment: In the case of Janice Rand, it should be noted that she worked her way up the ratings (noncom ranks) before receiving a commission. It would make sense for her to be older than others of her rank since she had served pretty much a whole career as a noncom already.